# Extreme memory consumption when using pipeline in 7zip extraction

Tags: powershell, 7zip

In our company we are packing db backups with 7zip for compression. I have been making a PowerShell script which extracts the backups and restores the db. When PowerShell passes the pipe output of 7zip to the restoring utility it tries to hog all of the system RAM.

Code:

```
7z e path\DBbackup.7z -so | restore_utility.exe
```

Notes:

Code works in cmd.

db size ~3gb after extracting.

RAM use at 90% . PowerShell itself had 8GB.

I say it is the restore utility but it happens with PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: from what i can tell, your code will run the `Restore_Utillity.exe` file _once for every line of output from the `7z` command_. you may want to capture the output of `7z` ad pass it all as one item to your util.

Comment: I guess `restore_utility.exe` stalls the pipeline till `7z` is finished, have tried a more native PowerShell pipeline command like: `7z e path\DBbackup.7z -so | Foreach-Object {restore_utility.exe $_}`?

Comment: @iRon thanks for suggestion, tried it now. it solved the memory issue but 7zip stalled.

Comment: (7z e path\DBbackup.7z -so) | Foreach-Object {restore_utility.exe $_} ?

Comment: @somebadhat that just does what ```7z e path\DBbackup.7z -so | restore_utility.exe``` did

Comment: Apparently PowerShell doesn't automatically buffer the input if the input cmdlet (/program) is faster then the output cmdlet (/program), but you might buffer it yourself like:  `7z e path\DBbackup.7z -so | Foreach-Object {$Buffer = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]}, {$Buffer.Add($_)}, {$Buffer} | Foreach-Object {restore_utility.exe $_}`